# Returning average vales along with a specific row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries. One returns the class average, lowest result and highest result. The second returns a specific students results. I am trying to bring the two queries together into one query so that it shows the specific students result as well as the min, max and average results for the class. Anything I have tried has resulted in errors. Is there something simple I am missing? Two queries below:

```
SELECT Module.ModuleTitle, Module.ModuleDescription, 
MIN(StudentModule.StudentGradeFinal) as lowres, 
MAX(StudentModule.StudentGradeFinal) as topres, 
AVG(CAST(StudentModule.StudentGradeFinal as DECIMAL(9,2))) as averageres
FROM StudentModule
join Module on StudentModule.ModuleId = Module.ModuleId
WHERE Semester = 'Spring'
AND Module.ModuleId in 
(
SELECT Module.ModuleId FROM Module 
Join StudentModule on Module.ModuleId = StudentModule.ModuleId
Where StudentId = '40104002'
)
GROUP BY Module.ModuleTitle, Module.ModuleDescription

SELECT Module.ModuleTitle, Module.ModuleDescription, StudentGradeFinal
FROM StudentModule
join Module on StudentModule.ModuleId = Module.ModuleId
WHERE Semester = 'Spring' AND StudentModule.StudentId = '40104002'
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you want as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two queries that always return only one row (the avg/min/max one and the student details one). If you want to "merge" them in a single result, all you have to do is use the two queries as inline views and join them on something that is always true, like 1=1.

So:

```
select * from
(
first query here
) a
join
(
second query here
) b
on 1=1
```

Be careful tho - make sure the queries only ever return a single row, otherwise you'll start getting cartesian products and those generate all sorts of weirdness.

Hope it helps

Comment: There are two modules returned so two rows for each query. Your suggestion worked with returning values with the two queries linked. But instead of two results being returned, there are 4. The specific students result is being duplicated.

Comment: instead of using 1=1 on the join i used on a.ModuleTitle = b.ModuleTitle
 this is exactly what i needed. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @user4184963 glad it helped!